# Show values in in percentages by class in power BI

Tags: bar-chart, powerbi, percentage

I the following table with classes and student's score on those clase:

[image]

I have shared that test data in this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Jqer6ObhpA4OpxY8ymXunMiL4hg4tO8/view?usp=sharing) on google drive.

From there I'm countin  the cases for each score like this:

```
good_count = CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Hoja1'[class]);
    'Hoja1'[score]
        IN { "good" })
```

From there, I have this plot with is the count of scores by class:

[image]

But I need to show this as percentages of scores by class, but if I select to show the values as percentages in powerBI

[image]

This are shown as percentages of scores overall not by class, E.G. for class one and two, percentages should be around 50-50 for scores good and bad. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest putting the `score` on the legend and using a single measure:

```
%Count =
    DIVIDE(
        COUNT(Hojal[score]),
        CALCULATE(COUNT(Hojal[score]), ALL(Hojal[score]))
    )
```

[image: Chart using Legend]